# Why nginx does not cache scripts with .html extension?

Tags: php, apache, caching, nginx

I have nginx/1.4.2 + Apache and I want to cache all requests with nginx. This location rule creates cache files for .php, but not for .html:

```
    location ~* \.(html|php)$ {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
            proxy_set_header Host my-host-name.com;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

            add_header cache "html";

            proxy_cache default;
            proxy_cache_min_uses 1;
            proxy_cache_valid  1d;
            proxy_cache_key "$host|$request_uri";
            proxy_hide_header "Set-Cookie";
            proxy_ignore_headers "Cache-Control" "Expires";
    }
```

Header "cache" added to response, so location is working.

I have tried with "location / " - requests to scripts with .php extension (and without any) stored in cache. For scripts with .html extension nginx does not create cache.

I can't find reason why nginx ignores scripts with .html extension. Renaming scripts to .php - it's not the way. I have CMS and it makes human readable URLs for pages with .html, there are thousands pages in Google index, and now renaming will cause site reindexing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because your CMS returns `Set-Cookie` headers.

Comment: Yes! Because in config I have:
proxy_hide_header "Set-Cookie";
so, after nginx we can't see if "Set-Cookie" header exists or not. And if CMS try to send cookies, nginx will disable cache